# bootstrap assets should work only in admin - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline, sass

I am little confusing that I am using bootstrap in rails project. I want use bootstrap in admin areas and not in home. But It doesn't work. I have added **@import "bootstrap"** into stylesheet/admin/admin.css.scss - not working. But If I add this into stylesheet/application.css.scss it's working, but it's override all other css styles and alos apply on home page which I don't want.! Project dir [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Ni5.png).

I have added javascript and css include tag into views/layout/admin.html.erb same as application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Any another way to include only admin/*.css files into admin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your stylesheet folder create an admin.css.scss file with the following content:

```
/**
 * admin.css.scss
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ./admin  
 */
```

Then, in your admin layout you can include just the newly created admin.css.scss stylesheet, like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "admin.css.scss", :media => "all" %>
```

It will act as a loader of all css/scss files in the "admin" subfolder.

Comment: I also recommend doing same for .js files. Because bunch of js files are automatically imported with Bootstrap.

Comment: @svilenv your solution worked on my local machine but when I deploy to Heroku, it gives error. https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/434 can you help about this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @svilenv is correct but you need also add the assets on config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w[admin.css]
```